# Null object from view in ASP.NET MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a simple inventory application where the user create an order by selecting the items he wants to be delivered, fill a form with the name of the recipient and then the order get processed.

First of all I have an `OrdineScarico` class that stores a collection of InventoryItems to be processed (like a cart), a `DeliverDetails` class that stores the recipient name

```
public class OrdineScarico
{
    private List<SingoloOrdine> ordineCollection = new List<SingoloOrdine>();

    // collection methods
}

public class SingoloOrdine
{
    public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

public class DeliverDetails
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserire il nome del ricevente")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

and then a `ConfermaScaricoViewModel` class -in a different namespace- for wrapping them up

```
public class ConfermaScaricoViewModel
{
    public OrdineScarico OrdineScarico { get; set; }
    public DeliverDetails DeliverDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I have these action methods in the `ScaricoController`

```
public ViewResult Conferma()
{
    return View(
        new ConfermaScaricoViewModel
        {
            OrdineScarico = GetScarico(),
            DeliverDetails = new DeliverDetails()
        });

}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Conferma(ConfermaScaricoViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repositoryProcessor.ScaricaItem(viewModel.OrdineScarico, viewModel.DeliverDetails);
        viewModel.OrdineScarico.Clear();

        return View("Confermato");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(
            new ConfermaScaricoViewModel
            {
                OrdineScarico = GetScarico(),
                DeliverDetails = new DeliverDetails()
            });
    }
}
```

where `GetScarico()` reads the `OrdineScarico` instance from the active session

```
private OrdineScarico GetScarico()
{
    OrdineScarico scarico = (OrdineScarico)Session["Scarico"];
    if (scarico == null)
    {
        scarico = new OrdineScarico();
        Session["Scarico"] = scarico;
    }
    return scarico;
}
```

This is the view code:

```
@model GestioneMagazzino.WebUI.Models.ConfermaScaricoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Conferma";
}

<h2>Conferma scarico</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="text-left">Ricevente:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliverDetails.Nome, new { @class="col-md-7" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Conferma" />
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that when the POST action method is called, I get a null value for the `OrdineScarico` argument, and the ModelState is always false. I also tried adding an hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrdineScarico)
```

but the `OrdineScarico` argument is always null when the POST method is called, while it's not when the controller renders the view.

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: You cannot bind a collection of complex objects to an input. And in any case, `ordineCollection` is a field not a property so would not bind even if you did create an input for each property of each item in the collection - but that would be crazy - just get the collection again in the POST method

Comment: Thanks. I just deleted the OrdineScarico from the POST method

Answer (score 0):

you must use @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrdineScarico)
also may be DeliverDetails has other field that you must set value for it.

you can use break point on line :
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
in method post of Conferma.
run code and when code arrived to break point, 
move cursor to the ModelState and wait to see data in it.
on values check all entities and find which property has error and you can see the message of error.

edit: cause you have not send any data for OrdineScarico. so it will be null in post action.
the OrdineScarico has a list member so
you should add this.

```
<input hidden name="OrdineScarico.ordineCollection[]" value="@value">
```

Comment: I used the helper you suggest, it's written in the post. Debugging clearly shows that DeliverDetails is ok, OrdineScarico is null. In the end, considering that OrdineScarico is at session level, I stripped that from the equation